# Что значит srand(time(NULL)) и rand()%10 в моей программе?

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Задача, написать программу, которая генерирует последовательность из 10 случайных чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 10, выводит эти числа на экран и вычисляет их среднее арифметическое.

```
int main() {

          int count,i;
          float sr,summ=0;
          srand(time(NULL));

          for ( i=0;i<10;i++) {
                count=rand()%10;
                summ += count;
                printf(" %d ",count);
          }
         sr = summ/10;

         printf("SR = %.2f",sr);

}
```

Не могу разобраться. Что значат строки:

```
srand(time(NULL));

count=rand()%10;
```

Может как-то можно иначе написать?

Comment: вот тут например посмотрите: http://hashcode.ru/questions/40405/c-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-srand-time-null

Comment: count=rand()%10;

 - rand()// вернёт псевдослучайное число
   (читай ссылку выше) (ну например 21)
 - 21%10// будет найден остаток от
   целочисленного деления (при `%10` он
   всегда будет 0-9)
 - если надо сделать рандом от 5 до 14
   то `(rand()%10)+5` в результате  получим 5-14

гугол выдал http://ci-plus-plus.blogspot.ru/2011/07/blog-post_27.html

Comment: @SleepingOwl, программа-то неправильнв написана. Должно быть rand()%10 + 1.

Comment: @dzhioev, моя правка не касалась содержательной части вопроса. Это код автора.

Comment: Ээээто не мой,это я где-то увидел,и разобраться не мог.

Comment: @rolton, 

    srand(time(0))

это установка начального значения генератора. По задумке программиста, для того, чтобы при каждом запуске выдавались разные последовательности чисел.

Однако, учтите, что запущенная в цикле из скрипта, например

     #!/bin/bash
     i=0
     while [ $i -lt 10 ]
     do
      ./a.out
      i=$[i+1]
     done

напечатает 10 одинаковых последовательности (секунда не успеет измениться).

Наверное, надежней будет

     srand(getpid() + time(0));

Если непонятно, прочтите `man getpid`.

Answer (score 1):

`srand(time(0))` это установка начального значения генератора. По задумке программиста, для того, чтобы при каждом запуске выдавались разные последовательности чисел. Однако, учтите, что запущенная в цикле из скрипта, например `#!/bin/bash i=0 while [ $i -lt 10 ] do ./a.out i=$[i+1] done` напечатает 10 одинаковых последовательности (секунда не успеет измениться). Наверное, надежней будет `srand(getpid() + time(0));` Если непонятно, прочтите `man getpid`

`count=rand()%10;`
`rand()` вернёт псевдослучайное число (ну например 21)
`21%10` будет найден остаток от целочисленного деления (при `%10` он всегда будет 0-9) - если надо сделать рандом от 5 до 14 то `(rand()%10)+5` в результате получим 5-1